# How does classifier predict a class? (for tensorflow/keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I want to implement the model by myself and thus have to know how does it classify the data. I build a model for 12-class classifier and it predicts fine. But the last conv layer just outputs 12 floating point value and I don't know how it suddenly predicts the right class.

Can someone explain for me? Like is it depend on some threshold or it chooses the max value or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [`SparseCategoricalAccuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SparseCategoricalAccuracy), it's equivalent to this computation:

```
acc = np.dot(sample_weight, np.equal(y_true, np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1))
```

This means that it calculates the frequency with which the maximum value per row of `y_pred` matches `y_true`. For instance:

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
m.update_state([[2], [1]], [[0.1, 0.6, 0.3],  # max at 1 
                            [0.05, 0.95, 0]]) # max at 1 
m.result().numpy()
```

```
0.5
```

Because `[2] != [1]` and `[1] == [1]` so 0.5 of the time, they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a flatten layer to your model followed by a dense layer. The dense layer should have 12 nodes and use the softmax activation as shown below' Your model will now output a list of 12 probability values for each image.

```
flatten=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(last_conv_layer)
output = Dense(12, activation='softmax')(flatten)
#after you train you can evaluate your model on your test set using model.evaluate() 
#to make Predictions use model.predict()
predictions=model.predict(.....
#you can get the index of the predicted class for the images you predict with
for p in predictions:
    predicted_index=argmax(p)
    print (predicted_index)
```

documentation for model.evaluate and model.predict is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) Don't forget to recompile your model after you add the two layers.